# boilerpy3 returns HTTP Error 403: Forbidden

Tags: python, web-scraping, http-error

In BoilerPy3 using extractors, on some websites I get 'HTTP Error 403: Forbidden.' Looking into the code, it looks like it calls urllib and will only take the url without headers. How do I get around this?

Perhaps someone could create a 'boilerpy' tag?

```
from boilerpy3 import extractors
extractor = extractors.ArticleExtractor()

url = 'https://www.enca.com/south-africa/benghazi-hospital-security-tightened-following-car-bombing'
try:
    doc = extractor.get_doc_from_url(url)
except HTTPError as e:
    print (e)
```

Answer (score 4):

Instead of trying to modify the `urllib` call, it'd be easier to just handle the request yourself, e.g. with the [`requests`](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/) library, then call `BoilerPy3` with the result. For example:

```py
import requests
from boilerpy3 import extractors


headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) '
                  'Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36'
}
url = 'https://www.enca.com/south-africa/benghazi-hospital-security-tightened-following-car-bombing'
extractor = extractors.ArticleExtractor()

resp = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
if resp.ok:
    doc = extractor.get_content(resp.text)
else:
    raise Exception(f'Failed to get URL: {resp.status_code}')
```

That should get you the text as expected.

Comment: Thank you very much! Currently, my up votes don't register.